# Web page Redirection using Login Control and LoginView after successful Login

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms, loginview

Please Notice the Master Page Code here

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="registerLink" runat="server" href="~/LogReg.aspx">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/LogReg.aspx">Log in</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="manage" runat="server" class="username" href="~/Account/Manage.aspx" title="Manage your account">
                            <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName2" runat="server" CssClass="username" />
                        </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a id="A2" runat="server" href="~/Logout.aspx">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

This is the login page code

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" Height="198px" Width="297px" DisplayRememberMe="False" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" UserNameLabelText="Email:">
            <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <LoginButtonStyle Font-Size="Small" />
            <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" CssClass="float-right" Width="180px" Height="12px" />
            <LabelStyle CssClass="float-left" />
            <TitleTextStyle CssClass="task-title" />
        </asp:Login>
```

The authentication event of the login control looks like :

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string un = Login1.UserName;
        string pw = Login1.Password;

        var c = db.customers.Where(s => s.customer_email == un && s.customer_password == pw && s.customer_deleted != true);
        if (c.Count() == 1)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            //Something to redirect //Response.Redirect(Page.PreviousPage.ToString());
        }
        else
            e.Authenticated = false;

    }
```

the problem is that when I use Response.Redirect function here, it successfully redirects, but the loginView Template goes back to anonymousTemplate. And if I do not use Redirection, the template changes to LoggedInTemplate, but I want to redirect it to previous page. I have used destinationPageUrl Property but it's behavior is same. Thank You for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is after calling Authenticate event, Login control needs to create **FormAuthentication** cookie.

If you want to redirect the authenticated user to a page, you can use **LoggedIn** event.

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // User is authenticated, so do something here.
}
```

Normally, we pass **ReturnUrl** in query string to Login Page. If Login control see the **ReturnUrl**, it will redirect back to that Url.

For example, `http://www.yoursite.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAbout%2f`

Comment: Page.PreviousPage is showing null in this event, can you please also tell me what step should be taken to redirect to whatever the previous page other than using sessions?


Thanks, got it now.

Comment: You can try **Request.UrlReferrer**. However, I do not recommend either one, because they are not reliable. Instead, we normally use **ReturnUrl in QueryString**.